# SQL Query: similar text in Database

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, compare, string-comparison

My DB holds Documents (saved in a longtext field) how can I get a percentage or so, to say, the new doc is ~70% the same document as doc12345?

This will stop people to create a copy of an existing doc by only change a view words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can find your answer [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2014/12/20/string-comparisons-in-sql-the-longest-common-substring/) #The Longest Common Substring

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that your database is a mysql, but just to show another interesting [link](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/02/05/finding-similar-strings-with-fuzzy-logic-functions-built-into-mds/) for T-SQL SQL Server user, check this article that explain how to use builtin library for search for similiarity.

The keyword to research your requirement is **Fuzzy String Searching**